# Mysql - select distinct clientcode with the highest average

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table in which are stored star ratings for clients, so:

**ref,clientcode,date,comment,stars**

The same clientcode can appear many times.

I need to select the distinct clientcode with the highest average number of stars. Any suggestions how to get this

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried :)

Comment: Please show some sample data and what is the desired output

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    t1.clientcode clientcode,
    t2.sum sum,
    t3.count count,
    CASE t3.count WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE t2.sum / t3.count END average
FROM
    t1
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            clientcode, 
            SUM(stars) sum
        FROM t1
        GROUP BY clientcode
    ) t2 ON t1.clientcode = t2.clientcode
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            clientcode, 
            COUNT(stars) count
        FROM t1
        GROUP BY clientcode
    ) t3 ON t1.clientcode = t3.clientcode
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    t1.* 
FROM 
    table t1 
WHERE 
    t1.stars IN 
    (
        SELECT 
            MAX(t2.stars) 
        FROM 
            table t2 
        WHERE  
            t2.clientcode = t1.clientcode
    )
```

Comment: There is no average here tho.

Answer (score 0):

this will show the average value of stars for distinct clientcode

```
SELECT avg(stars) from t1 group by clientcode;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try query given below.

```
select avg(`stars`) AS `avgstar` ,`clientcode`  from `t1` group by `clientcode` order by `avgstar` DESC
```

Here  `group by clientcode` will be get record for every distinct `clientcode` and `order by avgstar` where `avgstar is average of stars field value for each clientcode` in Descinding order.

thanks

Comment: Thanks to everyone for suggestions. I used this one as it was the simplest (and therefore easiest for me to understand!). It works brilliantly. When I implemented it, I collected the results in an array enabling me to choose any of the top 5 results which was just what I needed

Comment: Hi, If you like this answer then please vote it up and accept this answer :)